# Hadoop MongoInputFormat Read Preference does not work to Mongodb Shard

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark job (PySpark) running a query to mongo. I intended to fire the query to secondary.

I have a mongo input uri like below

```
'mongo.input.uri': 'mongodb://'+host+':27017/'+dbName+'.'+collection+'?readPreference=secondary'
```

As per my understanding, having readPreference=secondary as option passed to mongo input uri is the way to make it read from secondary (ref: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Configuration-Reference)

However, when I run the job, I see spike on mongo fault at my primary nodes monitoring. When I checked the log at primary nodes, it is confirmed that query run against primary instead of secondary.

What did I do wrong? Did I wrongly placed the configuration? Is it only working for normal replica set, and not for shard?

Note:
Mongodb setting is sharded with version 2.6.X